# Compounding negative returns?

Tags: equities, finance

Assume you're short AAPL. Say you sold short at 24.28 as of 2016-01-01 and cover 2021-09-13 on 149.74. So your return is (24.28-149.74)/24.28 or -517%.

If you get the daily returns of AAPL and just reverse the sign, then do a cumulative return, you instead get -90.2%. Obviously the correct number is -517% since as your short underperforms the position gets bigger since you need more cash to cover your position. So is it wrong to use cumulative returns in this context?

```
import pandas as pd
price_data = yf.download(['AAPL', 'SPY'], '2010-01-01')
y = price_data.loc['2016-01-01':]['Adj Close']['AAPL'].pct_change().dropna()
np.exp(np.log(1 + y.values).cumsum())[-1] - 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using simple returns and then treating them as log returns in the final calculation?

Comment: It's just to compound the returns. You can also just do: (1 + y.values).cumprod() - 1

Comment: Oh yes, they're equivalent - my mistake!

Comment: Among more material things, are you comparing price-only  return with total (dividend-adjusted) return here?

Answer (score 1):

Negating periodic returns for a long position is not equivalent to the cumulative returns on a short position.  Short positions have opposite *absolute gains*, not *relative* gains.

Take this example:

I start with a position of \$100. If the instrument gains \$5 (a 5% return), a long position makes \$5 and ends with a value of $105. If I have a short position, I lose \$5 and have a end total of \$95. If, on the second day, the instrument gains another \$5, the long position gains another \$5, which is a 4.7% return (5/105), but the short position loses \$5, which is a 5.26% *loss* (5/95).

The difference is that the *starting* value is different between long and short positions. So if an instrument goes up in value twice, the long position will have a smaller "return" than a short position, because the starting value after the first period will be higher (e.g. 105 vs 95 in the example).

Or, mathematically, if $r > 0$:

$\begin{aligned}
(1+r)(1+r) - 1 &= (1 + 2r + r^2) - 1\\
               &= 2r + r^2 \\
               &> 2r - r^2 \\
               &> 1 - (1 - 2r + r^2) \\
               &> 1 - (1-r)(1-r) \\
\end{aligned}$

It's one of the reasons that short ETFs are not recommended for long-term investing, since they must be rebalanced in order to match the proper multiple of daily returns, and losses can have a higher magnitude than the equivalent positive return.

Comment: So looking at your example the compound return in general is $-1+(1+s r_1)(1+s r_2)\cdots(1+s r_n)$ where s=1 if you are long and s=-1 if you are short, r are the daily  percent changes in the stock price.

Comment: @noob2: Would you care to look at my question https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/67909/6686? Thank you.